# geodesics in a Liouville's surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

A surface $S$ is a Liouville's surface if its coefficients of the first fundamental form satistifes $E=G=U+V$ and $F=0,$ where $U=U(u)$ and $V=V(v).$

I need to prove that the geodesics in a Liouville's surfaces  can be obtained by primitivation of the form $$\int \frac{\textrm{d}u}{\sqrt{U(u)-c}}=\pm\int\frac{\textrm{d}v}{\sqrt{V(v)+c}}. $$

My first try is to use the parallelism equations for a geodesic curve. If $\gamma$ is a geodesic, $\gamma(t)=\mathbb{x}(u(t),v(t)),$ where $\mathbb{x}$ is a local parametrization of $S,$ so

$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle u''+\Gamma_{11}^{1}(u')^{2}+2\Gamma_{12}^{1}u'v'+\Gamma_{22}^{1}(v')^{2}=0, \\
\displaystyle v''+\Gamma_{11}^{2}(u')^{2}+2\Gamma_{12}^{2}u'v'+\Gamma_{22}^{2}(v')^{2}=0.
\end{cases}
 $$

Computing the Christofell symbols, I find

$$\Gamma_{11}^{1}=\frac{U_{u}}{2(U+V)},\;\Gamma_{11}^{2}=-\frac{V_{v}}{2(U+V)},\; \Gamma_{12}^{1}=\frac{V_v}{2(U+V)\;}, \\
\Gamma_{12}^{2}=-\frac{U_{u}}{2(U+V)},\;\Gamma_{22}^{1}=-\frac{U_{u}}{2(U+V)},\;\Gamma_{22}^{2}=\frac{V_v}{2(U+V)}.
$$

So, applying this to the ODE,
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle u''+\frac{U_{u}(u)}{2(U(u)+V(v))}(u')^{2}+\frac{V_{v}(v)}{U(u)+V(v)}u'v'-\frac{U_{u}(u)}{2(U(u)+V(v))}(v')^{2}=0, \\
\displaystyle v''-\frac{V_{v}(v)}{2(U(u)+V(v))}(u')^{2}+\frac{U_{u}(u)}{U(u)+V(v)}u'v'+\frac{V_{v}(v)}{2(U(u)+V(v))}(v')^{2}=0.
\end{cases}
$$
But... well, I don't know if I can do something from here.

I tried to manipulate the equations, and I got

$$
\begin{cases}
2\left[u'\left(U(u)+V(v)\right)\right]'-\left((u')^{2}+(v')^{2}\right)U_{u}(u)=0 \\
2\left[v'\left(U(u)+V(v)\right)\right]'-\left((u')^{2}+(v')^{2}\right)V_{v}(v)=0
\end{cases}
 $$

Since, both equations equals to zero, one is equal to the other, so, manipulating,

$$2\left[\left(U(u)+V(v)\right)\left(u'-v'\right)\right]'+\left((u')^{2}+(v')^{2}\right)\left(V_{v}(v)-U_{u}(u)\right)=0, $$

and now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Your sign on $\Gamma^2_{12}$ is wrong, but it looks like you got it correct in the final differential equations. You lose information when you combine the two equations, so that's a dangerous game to play. Here's a suggestion, though: Remember that we have an arclength-parametrized geodesic, so $Eu'^2+Gv'^2 =1$. This gives us $$[(U+V)u']' = \frac12\frac{U'}{U+V} \quad\text{and}\quad [(U+V)v']' = \frac12\frac{V'}{U+V}.$$ Maybe you can get somewhere with that. You also don't care about the parametrization, so you'd rather get rid of $t$ and look for $dv/du = v'/u'$, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin sory, but how do you conclude that $[(U+V)u']'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{U'}{U+V}$?

Comment: That's your first equation (after "I tried to manipulate"), if you use $Eu'^2+Gv'^2=1$. Or did I mess up?

Comment: Hm.... I see.... maybe it could help. I need to find a way to not have the terms $u',v'$ in the equations

Comment: Apologies for my ambiguous use of the derivative mark. On $U$ and $V$ it denotes the derivative with respect to $u$ and $v$, respectively (evaluated at $u(t)$, $v(t)$), whereas the differentiation on the left-hand side is with respect to $t$. Sometimes it's bad to leave out the explicit reference to the variables. My fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the equation Ted Shifrin told you, $$ \frac{d}{dt}\left[ (U+ V) \dot{u} \right] = \frac{1}{2(U + V)} \frac{dU}{du}. $$

Therefore, 
$$ \frac{dU}{du} = 2(U + V) \frac{d}{dt} \left[ (U +V) \dot{u} \right] $$

$$ \therefore \frac{dU}{du} = 2 (U + V) \left[ \frac{d(U + V)}{dt} \dot{u} + (U + V) \ddot{u}  \right] $$

$$ = 2 (U + V) \frac{d(U + V)}{dt} \dot{u} + 2 (U + V)^2 \ddot{u}$$

$$  =\frac{d (U + V)^2}{dt} \dot{u} + 2 (U + V)^2 \frac{d \dot{u}}{dt}. $$

However, notice that

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[ (U + V)^2 \dot{u}^2 \right] = 2 (U + V) \frac{d(U+V)}{dt} \dot{u}^2 + (U + V)^2 2 \dot{u} \ddot{u}$$

$$ = \dot{u} \left[ \frac{d(U + V)^2}{dt}\dot{u} + (U + V)^2 2 \ddot{u} \right] = \dot{u} \frac{dU}{du}. $$

Since $\frac{dU}{du} \frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dU}{dt} $,
integrating you obtain for some constant A

$$ (U + V)^2 \dot{u}^2 = U - A. $$

The geodesic is parameterized by arclength, which implies

$$ (U + V)(\dot{u}^2 + \dot{v}^2) = 1 \implies $$
$$ (U + V)^2(\dot{u}^2 + \dot{v}^2) = U + V. $$

Substitute what you found for $(U + V)^2 \dot{u}^2$, reaching that $ (U + V)^2 \dot{v}^2 = V + A $ .

Finally, take square roots (here the sign possibilities appear) and "equaling the $ dt $s":

$$ \frac{(U + V)}{\sqrt{U - A}} du = \pm \frac{(U + V)}{\sqrt{V + A}} dv $$

Cancelling $ U + V $ and integrating, you reach, for some constant $ B $:

$$ \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{U - A}} = \pm \int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{V + A}} + B .$$

Comment: Hmm, this isn't quite right. The primes in my equation represented different derivatives, which is perhaps my fault. $U'$ should be $U'(u(t))$, not $(U\circ u)'(t)$. But perhaps you typed $dU/dt$ when you meant $dU/du$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry! It's just a typo, I'll edit it right away.